# Add multiple contacts to SMS Compose Task from isolated storage file

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage, isolatedstoragefile

I am trying to make an SMS Compose Task from which I can send group messages. The user adds phone numbers to an isolated storage file and I intend to take the numbers from there.

How do I take the phone numbers from there?
Also how to delete numbers from the isolated storage file?

Here is my isolated storage file code:

```
private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string fileName = "SOS Contacts.txt";
    using (var isoStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        // we need to check to see if the file exists
        if (!isoStorage.FileExists(fileName))
        {
            // file doesn't exist...time to create it.
            isoStorage.CreateFile(fileName);
        }
        // since we are appending to the file, we must use FileMode.Append

        using (var isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileName, FileMode.Append, isoStorage))
        {
            // opens the file and writes to it.
            using (var fileStream = new StreamWriter(isoStream)
            {
                fileStream.WriteLine(PhoneTextBox.Text);
            }
        }
       // you cannot read from a stream that you opened in FileMode.Append.  Therefore, we need
       //   to close the IsolatedStorageFileStream then open it again in a different FileMode.  Since we
       //   we are simply reading the file, we use FileMode.Open

       using (var isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, isoStorage))
       {
           // opens the file and reads it.
           using (var fileStream = new StreamReader(isoStream))
           {
               ResultTextBox.Text = fileStream.ReadToEnd();
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the `Application Settings` using `Isolated Storage` to store and retrieve data. As you're saving into the `Settings`, you'll be able to retrieve it anywhere from your application.

Perfect sample would be [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221360(v=vs.95).aspx).

The following sample is from msdn:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Using-Isolated-Storage-fd7a4233

Hope it helps!